# Best way to support "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" post data with WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, http, rest, post

I'm building a WCF service based on a W3C specification which defines a RESTful web service endpoint that accepts "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" post data.  WCF doesn't support this type of message encoding by default and I have found a number of different examples of creating a contract that looks like this:

```
XElement Query_Post(Stream postData);
```

And then within the implementation decoding the `postData` stream using the `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method.

Does anyone know of a more strongly typed way of supporting "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in WCF?

I would like my operation contract to be:

```
XElement Query_Post(string query, string [] params);
```

Comment: The fact that 24 hours later nobody knows how to do what should be such a basic think should indicate WCF is not best platform to build restful stuff.  Try OpenRasta, I believe it has a codec built in to handle x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to use `Stream` like [Raw HTTP POST with WCF](http://blogs.southworks.net/erossetto/2007/09/03/raw-http-post-with-wcf/) or what you are saying.
The reason is because WCF abstracts all the communication-level physical layout stuff out from the service code. Ideally, you would want to make a service that could turn into SOAP or REST just by flipping the switch.

To support it natively, you probably have to extend `WebHttpBinding` or make your own binding and implement [custom encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx). This is symmetric to the output like the linked post says. You have to twist its arms to get WCF to output non-XML/JSON stuff.

Comment: Do you have an example with a non-dead link?

Answer (score 2):

The WCF REST Contrib library enables this functionality:

https://github.com/mikeobrien/WcfRestContrib

It includes a POX formatter and form url encoded formatter and allows you to easily create your own. Formatters are mapped to mime types and automatically selected to serialize/deserialize the entity body based on the content type and accept headers.

Comment: That answer is 6 years old chief.

Comment: And it doesnt provide any help anymore chief