# Can I serve up web pages from a WCF Service NOT hosted in IIS?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service that will be used like a standard web service, but I also want to provide a configuration UI for various service settings. Is it possible to serve up standard HTML pages when the service is not being hosted in IIS? If so, what "gotchas" are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WCF is API used for creating services. Handling "configuration web pages" is out of scope of this API. If you really want to do something like that it means that you must create another REST (webHttp) service which will expose operations serving your web pages and accept HTTP POSTs from your web pages. It is possible but it is a lot of work to do because current WCF version [doesn't like content type of POSTed HTML forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604463/best-way-to-support-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-post-data-with-wcf) (application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data). You can in the same way implement your own self hosted "web server" by using [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. This is exactly how the WSDL help pages are served when the add the HTTP Help behavior to your service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "test")]
    Stream GetPage();
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public Stream GetPage()
    {
        var pageStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.htm"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        var context = WebOperationContext.Current;

        if (context != null)
        {
            context.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
        }

        return pageStream;
    }
}
```

You can also build in the page in a memory stream. Additionally, in WCF 4.5+, the [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx) type is provided for serving html pages. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is the top link when searching for "self hosted wcf webpage", so I though I'd add a more complete answer.  The answer by [@Jared-G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167041/8174889)  was close, but I wanted to host an Angular application as a frontend for my WCF service.  This meant being able to serve arbitrary js/css/img files as well.  An extension of the previous answer:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    // Webpage hosted at {Service URL}/Client
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Client/{*uri}")]
    Stream GetPage();
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public Stream GetPage(string uri)
    {
        if (uri == "") uri = "test.htm"; // Default page, if root path specified
        var basePagePath = "Client\\"; // Default path for webpage, relative to executable directory.
        var pageStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, basePagePath, uri), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        var context = WebOperationContext.Current;

        if (context != null)
        {
            context.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
        }

        return pageStream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this extra step! One question, how do you get VS to create a bundle with both the service and the web files?

Answer (score 2):

The gotchas of self-hosting instead of IIS generally consist of loss of instrumentation/recycling/recovery capabilities of IIS' app pools. However, self-hosted tends to perform substantially better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You could host the WCF service in a .NET application, or Windows Service on an HTTP or TCP port.

You would then have to host your site in another web server, and create a reference to your WCF service in your web application.

Comment: More information on creating a service host here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Comment: This doesn't answer the poster's question. One of the reasons I can see hosting an html page from WCF is for configuration or to avoid Cross Domain Scripting restrictions (REST service must reside on same domain as the server serving the HTML page.)