# Stream management when POSTing “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” to WCF

Tags: wcf, post, stream, request, dispose

I am posting data to WCF using the method suggested in [Best way to support "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" post data with WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604463/best-way-to-support-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-post-data-with-wcf)

I am following the example in http://blogs.southworks.net/erossetto/2007/09/03/raw-http-post-with-wcf/ and things seem to work fine. However, one issue is with the management of the stream in the request. I created a helper method like

```
    public static NameValueCollection ParsePOSTRequest(Stream input)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Dispose();

        return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
    }
```

I am calling this in all my methods so I can then look up the parameters easier. Now I noticed an issue here when trying to access information about the request via `WebOperationContext.Current`. Any property or method just throws an exception like `The System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties object has been disposed.` which apparently comes from the fact that the stream reader is being disposed before doing my business logic.

The question would be "is it right to dispose it?" Should I simply just close it instead? Or don't even bother closing at all? Is the framework still in need of that stream after my method finishes or it's all mine to play with?

Comment: Looking for the same question at the moment. Did you find the answer?

Comment: No, I did not find the answer. I just avoided to close/dispose the stream in the parsing method. I closed the stream in the caller method, in a finally block.