# How to return response as Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; from WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

After spending insane amount of time to finally make my WCF service accept requests as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`  (using Stream as suggested here [Best way to support "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" post data with WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604463/best-way-to-support-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-post-data-with-wcf))

it finally works.

However I get the response as

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">result</string>
```

But what I want is

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
result
```

Where can this be set up / hacked?

Currently method looks like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "generate_license", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST")]
[OperationContract]
string GenerateLicense(Stream period);
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have a response of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, are you posting a form to the client?  What are you trying to achieve by setting the response to the content type?

Comment: well maybe it doesn't make sense. What I am doing is accepting some simple call from outdated webservice and generating a license text and sending it to them, and they except it as raw text also.. not XML

Comment: If you want to send plain text then `text/plain` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I resolved it it seems:

```
public Stream GenerateLicense(Stream period)
        {
            Stream result = new MemoryStream();

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(result);
            sw.Write("LICENSE");
            sw.Flush();
            result.Position = 0;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            return result;
        }
```